# Application error in heroku django app deployment

Tags: django, heroku

can anyone help me why my app is giving the error?
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.

ERROR (heroku logs)

```
2020-05-16T15:43:07.360568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=algopediaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=74a12a50-a9cc-4269-8349-41fcb027be10 fwd="139.167.146.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-16T15:43:09.138262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=algopediaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=bdb6134c-31c6-457c-8bc2-3490610da6cf fwd="139.167.146.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-16T16:32:14.255438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=algopediaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=3bbecde1-6c5b-4dc2-9bc0-a05757fb2594 fwd="139.167.146.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-16T16:32:16.489639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=algopediaapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5cb98de5-14a7-4780-aa69-de1de72e7604 fwd="139.167.146.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I created profile , runtime and requirement file

Procfile

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn Loginproject.wsgi --log-file -
```

installed whitenoise and added it to settings file and also specified static root in settings.py

Comment: Do you have any dynos running?

Answer (score 0):

## H14 - No web dynos running

> This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. To fix it, scale your web dynos to 1 or more dynos:

`heroku ps:scale web=1` or if asks for an app run `heroku ps:scale web=1 -a your_heroku_appname`

> **Note:** This app name is your heroku app name found [here](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps)

Use the `heroku ps` command to determine the state of your web dynos. Get more info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running).

Comment: It is now showing bad request 400 error. But the app is working perfectly fine in my pc.